# Convert Generic T to type C#

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I'm trying to convert a generic method parameter to its type. The compiler is saying that I can't convert it

```
public ProvideRequest ProvideRequest<T>(int numberOfLines, 
                                        string ServiceType, 
                                        T addressIdentifier)
{
    var provideRequest = new ProvideRequest();
    provideRequest.NumberOfLines = numberOfLines;
    provideRequest.ServiceType = ServiceType;

    Type t = typeof(T);
    switch (t.GetType().Name)
    {
        case nameof(GoldAddressKeyIdentifierType):
            provideRequest.RequestIdentifier = 
              Convert.ChangeType(addressIdentifier, typeof(GoldAddressKeyIdentifierType))
            break;
    }

    return provideRequest;
}
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it a typo `t.GetType().Name`? It should be just `t.Name`

Comment: Generic types that subsequently test for the concrete type of their type parameters and modify their behaviour with a series of conditionals predicated on the type ***shouldn't be generic***. It's an abuse in all but a very few cases.

Comment: Your code would be significantly improved simply by making an overload with signature `public ProvideRequest ProvideRequest<T>(int numberOfLines, string ServiceType, GoldAddressKeyIdentifierType addressIdentifier)` to deal with type-specific actions and abandoning the switch idea. You'll end up with stronger type-checks and code that is easier to debug.

Comment: overloaded methods was the approach that I went for in the end

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when calling `t.GetType()` you don´t get the generic type but simply `System.Type` which is the runtime-type of `t`. What you want instead is the name of the generic type, which you can get via :

```
switch(typeof(T).Name)
```

Furthermore `Name` returns a string, so you have to write your `cases` as follows:

```
case MyNamepscae.GoldAddressKeyIdentifierType:
```

However I´d strongly recommend not to lery on typenames, just make a switch on the actual type itself. However the `switch`statement allows only strings, so use an `if` instead:

```
if(typeof(T) == typeof(GoldAddressKeyIdentifierType))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    Type t = typeof(T); // type of T
    switch (t.GetType().Name)
```

This switch is a mistake probably. t is of type Type. So t.GetType() is System.RuntimeType, so t.GetType().Name is always "System.RuntimeType" you know.

As far as I understand your problem, you need to remove .GetType(), you need

```
switch(t.Name)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest comparing two `Types`:

```
  ... 

  if (typeof(T) == typeof(GoldAddressKeyIdentifierType))
    provideRequest.RequestIdentifier = 
              Convert.ChangeType(addressIdentifier, typeof(GoldAddressKeyIdentifierType)); 

  return provideRequest;
```

However, *generics* (`<T>`) should work as generic type, any special conditions are *bad parctice*.

Comment: thanks I'm still getting a error with the convert.chaneType with this

Comment: according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08(v=vs.110).aspx `GoldAddressKeyIdentifierType` should implement `IConvertible`. Is it so? What is the error then?

Answer (score 1):

Since you know it is of type GoldAddressKeyIdentifierType, you should be able to cast the object as the class in your case method

```
provideRequest.RequestIdentifier = (GoldAddressKeyIdentifierType)addressIdentifier;
```